# how to use phone contacts instead of gmail contacts for social app in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have followed the tutorial of social chat demo in CN1 in which Shai Almog has done a greater work in this demo. I can send and receive message with this tutorial. Now, In the tutorial you must sign in with either gmail button or Facebook button. In my own case I want to get the contacts on phone and begin to send and receive message.

Pls, if I use GCM server Api key, GCM sender Id, pubnub published and pubnub subscribe key as it was used in social chat demo. Can only these be sufficient to accomplish this task?

If there is other things to add pls guide me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I built the tutorial as learning aid. Personally I would also have a server in the middle to store all the data, this would simplify a lot of the interaction and allow a single user to work from multiple devices.

The reason we didn't use it in the chat demo is that it predated our experiments with Parse and we didn't want to get into the complexity of building a custom server which seems really out of scope.

Getting the contacts of the phone is really easy, check out the contacts section of the [latest kitchen sink demo](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/kitchensink-ii.html) for a rather elaborate example of what you can do.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am very grateful. please can you suggest a server I can use as a backend?. I will be very glad if your suggestion can work with Parse4CN1 library.

Comment: I didn't have time to evaluate all the options here so any suggestion I make will be uninformed. The author of parse4cn1 wrote 2 guest posts on our blog covering the options: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-i-chose-my-replacement-for-parse-com.html & https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-i-chose-my-replacement-for-parse-com-part-2.html